# Apply Angular Impulse

Tags: sprite-kit, physics

Here is my code for the player and the ball that interact with each other. What I want to do is to apply force to the ball like if my player is shooting it. I want the ball to move away from my player with force. how can I apply Impulse or force to this. I have tried many times but I am a newbie with Sprite Kit.

```
- (void) Player {
    _Player = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"player1"];
    _Player.xScale = 0.09;
    _Player.yScale = 0.09;
    _Player.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/4, self.size.height/2);
    _Player.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:_Player.size];
    _Player.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    [self addChild:_Player];
}

- (void) TheMethodForBall {
    SKSpriteNode *sprites = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"ball"];
    sprites.xScale = 0.19;
    sprites.yScale = 0.19;
    sprites.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:sprites.size];
    sprites.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    sprites.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
    sprites.physicsBody.allowsRotation = YES;
    sprites.physicsBody.restitution = YES;
    sprites.physicsBody.angularVelocity = 4;
    sprites.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
    [self addChild:sprites];
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I think you want to apply an impulse like a kick ?

You need the following, maybe when you touch the screen / or a button

```
[_myBall.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(somePowerX, somePowerY)];
```

Here is another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543200/i-want-to-make-a-soccer-ball-by-ios-spritekit/19590761#19590761) that will help get you started

Also, this is a good [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/49625/sprite-kit-tutorial-space-shooter/) for beginners.

Comment: can someone please vote me up so I can start voting on answers I get. thank you I need at least 15 reputations. I can't show my appreciations for the answers I receive.

Comment: Yay :D +1's 4 Everyone!